# Custom Wordpress Template For Category

Tags: wordpress, templates, custom-wordpress-pages

I have two categories that need a special template. Each has one post and will display differently. So I read that if the category is named, for example, 'testing' and the template name is 'testing.php' then it should use that correct? 
Why would it not? I keep previewing the post and it just redirects to the home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naming the template `testing.php` won't work. You need to use either a slug or ID of your category, so either `category-testing.php` or `category-ID.php` if you know the ID of category (ie. you're not making a theme for release and your IDs are constant).

Answer (score 2):

[Category templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates), which your version of WordPress has, can do it.

Answer (score 0):

What version of WordPress are you running. WordPress 3.0 is new and will support what you want out of the box as you described.

Comment: Running 2.9.2, you can use `category-CAT_SLUG.php`